# PDF and EPUB from one source?

Tags: pdf, html, epub

I am an author of a free e-book which I distribute both in PDF, (X)HTML, and EPUB formats.

Currently I generate (by scripts written by me) HTML and EPUB from source XHTML files, and PDF from an OpenOffice document.

It is inconvenient as I need to edit both XHTML and OpenOffice files and keep them in sync.

Are there any software which can generate quality PDF and quality EPUB (and HTML) from one source?

Comment: What about the pandoc software?

Comment: Does pandoc support HTML classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/), it is a free epub editor; you can import in it your html files and manually create and edit the epub as you like it.

There is also [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), an ebook cataloging software that amongst other features, can convert files between a wide number of ebook formats.